# Can't install QGIS on Linux / "E: broken packages"

Tags: qgis, installation, linux

I am trying to install QGIS the first time on Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon by following the official QGIS-Installation instructions for Debian/Ubuntu.
(Please note, that I am Linux beginner and wouldn't be asking here if I had found any proper solution in the internet myself.)

I got stuck here:

```
    apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-3d3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-gui3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.16.3+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.16.3+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.16.3+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: grass740 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libqgis-app3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-core3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-gui3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.16.3 but it is not going to be installed
**E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

Comment: Might be a Linux Mint issue, as some other people have had similar issues: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=301762 Any reason not to go with Ubuntu? It is a much more widely used OS.

Comment: Which package source are you using? Please add to your question the output of: `apt policy qgis`

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto Problem solved: indeed, I put on Ubuntu for this reason (meanwhile smashing my windows10 finally) and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

No neeed to leave Linux Mint. You just have to use the proper **Ubuntu** version name, which is **focal** instead of **bionic**.

The QGIS download instruction is wrong when it tells you to use

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/debian `lsb_release -c -s` main"
```

which works for ubuntu and debian, but not for Linux Mint which has different version names.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main"
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to install QGIS on Linux Mint is via flatpak. This is a one-liner in your terminal. Have a look here, where I posted the answer:

[Installing QGIS 3.28 on Linux Mint Una (Ubuntu Focal)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445015/installing-qgis-3-28-on-linux-mint-una-ubuntu-focal/460902#460902)