# Installing QGIS 3.28 on Linux Mint Una (Ubuntu Focal)

Tags: qgis, installation

I found out a strange behavior (bug in digitizing) in my Project which is based on QGIS 3.26. To continue my work, I have to switch to 3.28 as fast as possible! No problem - I tought but the https://qgis.org/debian repository is just delivering me 3.26.3 and not 3.28 as it should like it mentioned [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#quickstart)

What am I doing wrong? I followed the instructions step by step. Im running Mint Una based on Ubuntu Focal. My qgis.sources looks like that:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: focal
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Comment: If you scroll down the page you've linked to from 'here' it mentions that default repositories for Ubuntu and Debian sometimes hold earlier versions - it then lists a fix which involves adding deb-lines to your sources qgis.file, have you given that a try?

Comment: yes, I tryed it also with the nigthly, the ubuntugis and the nigthly-ubuntugis repro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only QGIS 3.26.x is available for Focal from the qgis.org repos because the version of QT required for 3.28 is not available in Focal.

See note [#6](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id14) for Focal under the [supported distribution versions](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#repositories:%7E:text=Supported%20distribution%20versions%3A):

[image]

You could:

- install the [QGIS Flatpack version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.qgis.qgis),
- [upgrade to Linux Mint 21 Vanessa](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=4378) which is based on Ubuntu 22.04
- install a 22.04 based virtual machine using VirtualBox or Gnome Boxes.

Comment: Yes, I see! That is the reason!

Answer (score 0):

The following is NOT specific for the installation of QGIS 3.28 but for the newest stable version. However, as the question refers problems specific to QGIS 3.26, which are fixed in newer versions of QGIS, the followin may still apply.

I ran into the exact same problem : I installed QGIS on my Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon which is based on Ubuntu focal  via the debian package manager using  this installation recommendations: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu ... and ended up with QGIS 3.26.

To get the newest stable version I highly recommend to install QGIS as flatpak but NOT via the Linux Mint Software manager, as this will install a very old QGIS version (at least on my Distribution). Instead have a look here:  https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#flatpak

The only thing you need to do is to give the following command in your terminal :

```
flatpak install --from https://dl.flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.qgis.qgis.flatpakref
```

That's it!
This will install a flatpak version from the newest stable version of QGIS, which is QGIS 3.30 (by June 2023).

PS: On my distribution, you won't need to run QGIS from the terminal, but it will appear in the menu:

[image]